# Verifying Login user through loop in Python

Tags: python, authentication

I am trying to verify user by ensuring only registered users with a department can have access to the department template in the application. I want a situation whereby once a user enters his login details, his department would be checked by the system and through his login detail, the template for his department would be open. So it is the work of the application to identify the department he is through his login details and open the right template for him.

I want the system to loop through the other departments if he's not found in the first department, to see if he is registered in one of the others. Here's my code:

```
def verifyUser(self):
    self.db_connection()
    try:
        username = self.user.text()
        password = self.pwtx.text()
        result = self.conn.execute(
            """SELECT *
               FROM newUser_general 
               WHERE userID = ? AND dept = 'Comp Dept' """,
            (username, password)
        )  # include dept
        print("SQL Statement executed")
        if (len(result.fetchall()) > 0):
            print("user found")
            self.compDept()

        else:
        print("user not found")

    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
```

Comment: what if you just remove the where condition `dept = 'Comp Dept'` ?

Comment: that is what validates the department and sends the user to the right template.

Comment: @CEO I assume usernames are unique keys in your database? Get the user by username _and password_ (which you've left out) and then validate / return their department template in python - don't validate in SQL and don't make multiple SQL queries. If your usernames aren't unique, you probably have bigger problems.

Comment: the usernames are unique keys. Initially I was validating with username, password and department. Then I created only one department class. Now I have created multiple department classes and need to validate users' access. You know, I was a situation whereby a Computer science student on logging in will be shown template for computer Science, same thing with students from other departments, to be shown templates of their respective departments immediately their username and password are verified

Answer (score 1):

I've finally gotten it right.
I used an if and else conditional statement.
First I instantiated the departments like dept1 = "Comp sci", dept2 = "Statistics"
Then I did

````
```if dept1:
result = self.cursor.connect(result = self.conn.execute(
        """SELECT *
           FROM newUser_general 
           WHERE userID = ? AND dept = 'Comp Dept' """,
        (username, password))
else if dept2:
result = self.cursor.connect(result = self.conn.execute(
        """SELECT *
           FROM newUser_general 
           WHERE userID = ? AND dept = 'Statistics' """,
        (username, password))```
````

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a department table in your database, you can select all the department names or better their unique identifier first and store them in an array. Then you loop through the array and execute a request every time.

Another solution is to store the department of each user in the user table. Then when in the login process you can select his dept id.

Comment: the table already has a column for department. How do I loop through the login verification for the department, that is my challenge now.